# selected dots not swiping to next page in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, viewpagerindicator

I am developing new app  I have implemented dot indicator by using following https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView library  but I can't swipe to next page

below my current kotlin implementation code

```
class IntroductionPages: AppCompatActivity() {

  var pager: ViewPager? =null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.introduction_page)
        val pageIndicatorView: PageIndicatorView = findViewById(R.id.pageIndicatorView)
        pageIndicatorView.count = 3 // specify total count of indicators
        pageIndicatorView.selection = 0



       pager?.addOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int

            ) { /*empty*/

            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                pageIndicatorView.selection = position
               when(position){
                   0-> AnimationType.SLIDE
               }


            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) { /*empty*/
            }
        })

       val textView= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.skip)

        textView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, BookAppointment::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }


    }
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vector_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/vectors_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:background="@drawable/doctor_appointment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.426"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.158" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_doct"
        android:layout_width="272dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:text="@string/search_doct"
        android:textAppearance="@style/search_doct"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/some_id" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/get_list_of"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:text="@string/get_list_of"
        android:textAppearance="@style/get_list_of"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/search_doct"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_doct" />

    <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.477"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.801"
        app:piv_animationType="scale"
        app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
        app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
        app:piv_selectedColor="@color/gray_50"
        app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/gray_300"
        app:piv_viewPager="@id/viewPager"
        attrs:piv_padding="12dp"
        attrs:piv_radius="8dp" />




    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/pageIndicatorView"
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textAppearance="@style/skip"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.93"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my question is what I have to in order to implement correctly swipe function correctly so that I can swipe to next page

I want to implement this kind of approach

[image: dots indicator slider I want]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem fully but I can see that you want a IntroSlider which should slide and dots should move with slide.
So I have a IntroSlider which you can use and if you wish you can convert my java code with inbuilt java to kotlin converter in android studio. But I guess there will be no problem with java and kotlin both in your project. so here is the solution.

```
public class MainIntroSlider extends AppCompatActivity {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
private TextView[] dots;
private int[] layouts;
private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
private PrefManager prefManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_intro_slider);
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }
    // Making notification bar transparent
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_intro_slider);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


    // layouts of welcome sliders
    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.welcome_slide1,
            R.layout.welcome_slide2,
            R.layout.welcome_slide3,
            R.layout.welcome_slide4
    };

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    // making notification bar transparent
    changeStatusBarColor();

    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page if true launch MainActivity
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
    int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#9679", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        dots[i].setTextSize(13);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class));
    finish();
}

//  viewpager change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);

        // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
        if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            // last page. make button text to GOT IT
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // still pages are left
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

// Making notification bar transparent

private void changeStatusBarColor() {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

/**
 * View pager adapter
 */
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        assert layoutInflater != null;
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main_intro_slider">
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/layoutDots"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="@string/skip"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: Rajnesh thank you for answer but I want dots should move with slide I already have costume XML three layout

Comment: No problem! but If you see my code you can put you all three XML layouts in my code. Check for layouts = new init[] in my code below the comment // layouts of welcome sliders.

Comment: @RajneshSharma thank you for answer but I want dots should move with slide I already have costume XML three layout dot should move I have edit my question pleas check it

Comment: but I want to use my own library implementation

Comment: OK I don't know much about kotlin so I really don't understand your code!

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I want to implement correct sliding with my current library